# Grails Dependency Injection Problem

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-injection

I am having problems when using dependency injection with Services in Grails.

```
class ExampleService{

    def example2Service
    def example3Service

    def method1(){
       def result = example2Service.method2()
    }

}

class ExampleService{
    def example3Service

    def method2(){

       def result = example3Service.method3()
       return result 
    }

}

class Example3Service{

    def method3(){
        return true
    }

}
```

Basically in Example2Service, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when trying to call method3 in Example3Service.

I would appreciate any help than anybody can give me with this issue

thanks

Comment: did you check the obvious: i.e. that the test3Service is named Test3Service and is an appropriately named file?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly named. If I call it from TestService it works but I need to be able to call the method from Test2Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Injection needs to be initialized. (The same applies to other kinds of runtime meta programming, like augmenting Domain classes with their `save()` and `validate()` methods.)

A Grails application will be initialized when

- being run from the `grails run-app` command
- being run after having been deployed to a web server
- being run from the `grails test-app` command (*integration* tests, only; *unit* tests do not trigger initialization).

Involved classes are *not* initialized when

- executing a single Groovy file (i.e., by using `groovy`, `groovysh`, or `groovyConsole`)
- or when executing a *unit* test.

The following as an *integration test* should work:

```
class Test2ServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    def test2Service

    void testMethod2() {
        assert test2Service.method2() == true
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not writing a unit test or an integration test. The example of code is just to illustrate the problem that I am having.

Comment: Likely your problem is not properly isolated and your original question is missing required information.