# Grails Dependency Injection from Service

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-injection, grails-domain-class

I am trying to injecting my own service `elasticsearchService` from the following domain class:

```
class DocumentESO extends ElasticsearchObject{

  ElasticsearchService elasticsearchService

  def afterInsert() {
    elasticsearchService.save(this) // <-- Cannot invoke method save() on null object
  }
}
```

However, it tells me that it `Cannot invoke method save() on null object`. Here is my service:

```
@Transactional
class ElasticsearchService {
    @Transactional
    def save(ElasticsearchObject esObject) {...}
}
```

Did I misspell something? If I would use `ElasticsearchService elasticsearchService = new ElasticsearchService()` then it would work, but I don't have the transactional support anymore.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4012565/646993), robert mentions it needs to initialized, while using meta programming `save()` for example. Does it mean that I cannot go with dependency injection in this case?

Thus it would be:

```
  def afterInsert() {
    ElasticsearchService elasticsearchService = new ElasticsearchService()
    elasticsearchService.save(this) 
  }
```

??

Comment: Shot in the dark: autowiring is by default off in your version of grails?  e.g. see https://guides.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core-plugin-custom-authentication/guide/index.html#domainClasses - also my guess would be, that you will not partake in transactional behaviour for ES (e.g. there won't be un-index/delete ops after saving to ES and then rolling back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service injection in GORM entities is disabled by default since Grails 3.2.8.

You can turn on autowiring in this one particular domain class by adding to `DocumentESO`:

```
static mapping = {
       autowire true
   }
```

however it's not recommended: https://grails.org/blog/2017-05-09.html

Comment: Michal is correct, the "newer," way to deal with this is to use gorm listeners: https://guides.grails.org/gorm-event-listeners/guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks @virtualdogbert, that is what I've been looking for. Probably you would like to provide an answer.

Comment: @Michael_Szulc, thank you, very valuable answer.

Comment: @virtualdogbert If I follow your guide, then after `DocumentESO.save()` do I need to trigger `PostInsertEvent event = new PostInsertEvent(dataStore, doc)` on my own?

Comment: It's not my guide it's just one of Grails many guides. To answer your question no you shouldn't have to trigger the event, the should get triggered automatically.